# Create SSH tunnel and route MySQL traffic through using NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: mysql, ssh-tunnel, nginx-reverse-proxy

My company's goal is to route MySQL traffic through an SSH tunnel, but using a reverse proxy through NGINX. We created a Linux box in our Azure environment, but are struggling to complete the process.

I was going to open an SSH tunnel locally, and then route the reverse proxy to the local ssh tunnel address, however I am not sure that will work...

Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need nginx? SSH port forwarding/tunneling should handle everything.

Comment: How stable are you expecting this to be? Surely you are not using it for backend connections in production?

Comment: @EsaJokinen Unfortunately, we were planning on using it in production to connect to our cloud based SQL server for Magento. We figured running a cronjob to close and reopen the tunnel every evening would stabilize the tunnel enough.